# Handling runtime changes in Android for a simple app - do I need to use a Bundle?

Tags: android

I am making my first Android app, which consists of just editText's and Spinner's. Reading up on the activity cycle, I am wondering if it is even necessary to use the Bundle mechanism in my situation.

Since the state of the widgets are automatically persisted -
could I just call the getSelectedItem() method on the spinners and getText() on the EditText's within the onCreate() method for the Activity and pass that on to my newly re-created model object rather than using the Bundle mechanism? What are the advantages and disadvatanges of this approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The state of widgets it not automatically persisted. When you activity is destroyed it loses all the information about state. I recommend you saving you application state using shared preferences. Here is an example from google [developers site](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref). it allows you to save your application state by storing key-value pairs and it should suffice for your app.

Save the text and spinner item position in shared preferences when your activity is stopped - `onStop()` and restore the state in `onCreate()`.

```
public class Calc extends Activity {
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle state){
       super.onCreate(state);
       . . .

       // Restore preferences
       SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
       boolean silent = settings.getBoolean("silentMode", false);
       setSilent(silent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop(){
       super.onStop();

      // We need an Editor object to make preference changes.
      // All objects are from android.context.Context
      SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
      editor.putBoolean("silentMode", mSilentMode);

      // Commit the edits!
      editor.commit();
    }
}
```

Although you can save your application state by `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)` method, usually the better way will be to do that in `onPause()` or `onStop()` methods(the data will be saved for sure). Documentation says:

> Note that it is important to save persistent data in onPause() instead
>   of onSaveInstanceState(Bundle) because the latter is not part of the
>   lifecycle callbacks, so will not be called in every situation as
>   described in its documentation.

Comment: That doesn't seem right - the Android documentation specifically mentions that the onDestroy() method is called on the activity when something like a screen rotate happens. From a simple test we can see that the widgets retain their state with no coding, and this is mentioned in the documentation as well. Do you mean persisting through the destruction of the Application object? I'm not sure I need to do that.

Comment: Yes, I mean if you need to save state when the Application object is destroyed. In your case Android uses the bundle mechanism when it changes orientation on its own, so there is no need to use Bundle to persist state. Or maybe I got you wrong, what exactly you mean by recreated model object?

Comment: Ugh now I am confused, the documentation says to use onSaveInstanceState(Bundle) method to save the transient state of the activity (state of the UI). Which brings me back to my original question - why can't I just read the state of the widgets in the onCreate() method? I guess I just should try it and see what happens.

Comment: by model object I just meant the object that is being used to perform calculations for the app, which I assume is being destroyed along with activity since I will be creating it in the onCreate() method.

Comment: The state of widgets will be saved automatically for you. In onSaveInstanceState(Bundle) you should save state (key-values) of your app that Android isn't aware of. Just use getText() and getSelectedItem() in any place of ur activity, and don't worry, in ur case Android will save the transient state for you.

Comment: ok I think that's the answer I was looking for. The bundle will be used if there's anything the UI isn't aware of in my model object that needs to persist. Thank you.